# To get reference counting, do I have to clutter my APIs with shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, api, pass-by-reference, shared-ptr, reference-counting

I recently had the following **memory bug**, which is easy to spot here, but can be harder to detect in more complex code:

```
class Foo : public IFoo {
  const Bar& bar_;
public:
  Foo(const Bar& bar) : bar_(bar) {
  }
  void test() {
    // access bar_ here
  }
};

int baz() {
  IFoo* foo = NULL;
  if(whatever) {
    Bar bar;
    foo = new Foo(bar);
  }
  else {
    // create other foo's
  }
  foo->test(); // segmentation fault
}
```

The bug is that `Bar` immediately goes out of scope, is destroyed and then used in `foo->test()`. One solution is to create `Bar` on the heap, using `Bar* bar = new Bar()`. However, I don't like to do this because I'd have to keep the `Bar* bar` pointer at top-level so I can access and `delete` it at the end, even though `Bar` is something that is specific to that particular code block `if(whatever){}`.

Another solution is `boost::shared_ptr<Bar>`, but I cannot just write this:

```
  if(whatever) {
    boost::shared_ptr<Bar> bar(new Bar());
    foo = new Foo(*bar);
  }
```

since the `shared_ptr` goes out of scope immediately, too, destroying the contained object.

So in short, to get rid of this problem, I'd **have to use `shared_ptr` everywhere**, in `Foo` as member variable, in `Foo`'s constructor, etc. To eliminate these problems in general, all my APIs etc. have to use `shared_ptr`, which is kind of ugly. But, is it the right thing to do? So far, I have used it sometimes to create reference-counted objects, but I have kept my APIs clean of `shared_ptr`. How do you deal with this problem that, once you use `shared_ptr` you have to use it **everywhere**?

(Also, if you use these reference-counted pointers, you have to start worrying about if you really want `shared_ptr` or rather `weak_ptr` etc.)

And, what would I use as an equivalent to `Foo(const Bar& bar)`? `Foo(const shared_ptr<const Bar> bar)`?

Another option, of course, is to add reference counting inside the `Bar` and other objects yourself, using `pimpl` and your own counters, but that gets too tedious as a general rule.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually I **do** use `shared_ptr` everywhere... There are several ways to make it look less cluttered. One convention I use is typedefs for each defined class:

```
class AClass {
public:
    typedef boost::shared_ptr<AClass> Ptr;
    typedef boost::weak_ptr<AClass> Ref;
    //...
};
```

Makes the code much more readable :)

As for your specific problem, remember that you can pass bar by pointer -- you'd have to remember to allocate it on the heap though.

Comment: Thanks! I like the typedef solution. And I didn't know that `weak_ptr` would be seen as a reference? Interesting. (About heap allocation, I discussed that in my question :-)

Comment: @dehmann, weak_ptr as a reference is my own convention, however at least for me it makes sense -- weak_ptr doesn't own an object, just references to it.

Comment: I just "typedef" "boost::shared_ptr" globally into "sp" (via inheritance, since typedefs dont support templating). much less work

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to either not pass bar byref into Foo (in other words change Foos constructor) or copy it so you hold a duplicate in Foo. Of course in some cases this is not possible.

Regarding covering your code with `shared_ptr<Bar>`, the easiest solution is to typedef `shared_ptr<Bar>` to `BarPtr` or similar.

Comment: I think I have a good reason to pass by ref because it contains several hundred MB data.

Comment: You could have bar used a shared_ptr internally, to its data.  Then coping bar actually only copies the shared pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I understand that you provide a simplified version of your code, and without seeing the rest I don't know if what I am saying now is feasible.

Since `foo` is the longest-living object, how about creating the `Bar` instance inside it, and making other variables (`bar` in your code) references to that?

On the other hand, if `Bar` is really sepecific to the inside of the if block, `test()` should not need it at all.  In this case, there is no problem in keeping a pointer inside `Foo` and then deleting it at the end of the if block.  Otherwise, maybe it is not so specific to the block and you have to rethink your design a bit.

Comment: You have a good point when you say that maybe `Bar` should be created and destroyed inside `Foo`. On the other hand, I wanted to keep `Foo` small with minimal responsibilities. I think my situation is like this: `Foo` is a car. `IFoo` is a vehicle in general. `Bar` is a nice DVD player. So, the car contains a DVD player, which is definitely not something that a vehicle should care about in general, so it's specific to the car, but it's not that a DVD player couldn't live outside of a car.

Comment: @dehmann:  This makes no sense to me.  `Foo` should have the minimum necessary responsibilities, but one of its minimal responsibilities is holding onto all the data it's using.  If it's going to use a `Bar`, it needs to make sure it keeps the `Bar`.

Answer (score 1):

I would actually propose another solution...

I don't really like reference counting that much, not just the clutter, but also because it's harder to reason when multiple objects have a handle to the same item.

```
class IBar
{
public:
  virtual ~IBar() {}
  virtual IBar* clone() const;
};

class Foo: public IFoo
{
public:
  Foo(const IBar& ibar): m_bar(ibar.clone()) {}
  Foo(const Foo& rhs): m_bar(rhs.m_bar->clone()) {}
  Foo& operator=(const Foo& rhs) { Foo tmp(rhs); this->swap(tmp); return *this; }
  virtual ~Foo() { delete m_bar; }

  void swap(Foo& rhs) { std::swap(m_bar, rhs.m_bar); }

private:
  IBar* m_bar;
};
```

And now your code works, because I made a copy :)

Of course, if Bar was NOT polymorphic, then it would be much easier.

So, even though it's not using a reference, are you sure you actually need one ?

---

Let's get off track now, because there are a number of things you do wrong:

- `foo = new Foo(bar)` ain't pretty, how are you going to guarantee that the memory is deleted in case an exception occurs or somewhat introduces some `return` in the `if` clutter ? You should move toward an object that manages memory for you `auto_ptr` or the new `unique_ptr` from C++0x or Boost.
- instead of using reference counting, why does not `Foo` takes ownership ? `Foo(std::auto_ptr<Bar> bar)` would work too.

Shy from reference counting where it's not needed. Every time you *share* something you actually introduce a source of hard to track bugs in your code (and potentially side effects). That's why `Haskell` and the functional family are gaining popularity :)

Comment: The above has significantly different semantics to using a smart pointer.  If for example, the user needs to modify the object then they would be modifying their copy not the original.  There is also a performance cost depending on the size of the object.  Finally if objects are stored in separate lists then new objects are created for each list so you may have a memory issue.

Comment: Yes, it has a different semantic. That is the point after all. Too often I've seen people using `shared_ptr` just because they did not want to try and understand what was the life-cycle of the object and where it was needed. The cases where the owner of the memory is not clearly defined are few and far between.

Comment: You make a good point re use of shread_ptr to avoid investigate life-cycle, however, to some that is probably the biggest positive!  Search So and you'll find every 2nd question is answered with:  You should use smart pointers.  Your solution has no "owners" of resources and I'm finding it hard to see how this extreme is any better than using smart_ptrs.  In fact it is likely to use more memory and be slower, how is that better?

Comment: I don't want to talk about the "likely to be slower"... Now for the "better": it really depends on the problem. However from experience I can tell that if it's effectively easier in term of "memory management", it is not so easy when it comes to reasoning about the program. Which function changed my data ? From which instance ? How come I lost it ? ... I personally recommend using a "copy" approach over a "shared" approach anytime it's practical, because easier reasoning means easier debugging... and let's not worry about the "performance" until we know it matters!

Answer (score 1):

> Also, if you use these reference-counted pointers, you have to start worrying about if you really want shared_ptr or rather weak_ptr etc

There is no worrying if you follow your design and you understand what is `weak_ptr` (hint: it isn't a reference) and what it is for (hint: it isn't for "breaking cycles").

If you do start worrying, it's because you never had a design, or you don't understand `shared_ptr` design.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply move your bar object at a higher scope in order to prevent its deletion too soon.

```
int baz() {
  Bar bar;
  IFoo* foo = NULL;
  if(whatever) {
    foo = new Foo(bar);
  }
  else {
    // create other foo's
  }
  foo->test(); // no more segmentation fault
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but like I wrote in the question, I don't really want to mention `Bar` at all outside of the `if(whatever){}` block, because it's really specific to that code block.

Comment: @dehmann:  No, it's not specific to that code block.  If it was, you wouldn't be having the problem.  Either you're referencing it when you shouldn't, or you're using too small a scope for it.

Comment: Maybe it's time to break one the Rule and introduce a global object "defaultBar" (or a singleton) that can be referenced when you need to create a Foo with a Bar.